# Java - entityExpansionLimit. Where do I set this?

Tags: java, csv, command

I am using Java and when I try to write an array into a CSV file, I encountered the following error:

> The parser has encountered more than "64,000" entity expansions

I searched and found that I need to use entityExpansionLimit to solve this by typing in java command line: `-DentityExpansionLimit=100000`

But being new to Java and these kind of things, I don't understand where am I suppose to type that command. I tried typing that in command prompt but nothing happened

Can someone guide me? Am I supposed to navigate to a specific folder in command prompt?

Comment: Please show the code that is giving this error.  It is likely you have some recursive substitution going on; I would be surprised if you really had 64000 expansions in one line.  In general you are expected to show the code that is causing the problem. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: He is actually trying to work around a known bug in the JDK: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028111

Comment: Common problem.  We've hit this before too.

Answer (score 4):

With the option `-D` you can pass a system property to the `jvm` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)).

For example if you run you application with

```
cmd> java -Dfoo=bar MyMainClass
```

then you can retrieve it in your application using the [System#getProperty(String key)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) like this:

```
String foo = System.getProperty("foo");
System.out.println(foo); // will print bar
```

In you case the library that you are using is expecting to find a system property with the name `entityExpansionLimit` when "entity expansions" has exceeded the value 64,000 but it doesn't find it, i.e `System.getProperty("entityExpansionLimit")` returns `null`.

To pass that argument run you application by passing the jvm that system property

```
cmd> java -DentityExpansionLimit=100000 -cp <your-class-path> YourMainClass
```

Comment: by "MyMainClass" you are refering to my java file with main() inside?

Comment: @user2741620 Yes, including the package name!